# How to format phone numbers in bash with awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm coding a new script in **bash** to format phone number to a french standard.
Almost everything is done, but I don't know how to change values in a CSV files.

1. Specifications :

   - Delete all not numbers caracters ( except "+" if is in first position)
   - Substitutions :

     - 06xxx -> +336xxx
     - 07xxx -> +337xxx
     - +3306xxx -> +336xxx
     - +3307xxx -> +337xxx
2. Sample Data (admitting data will be in the third column of my csv file, with | separators) :

   ```
   ||0612345678|
   ||+33612345678f|
   ||+33712345678|
   ||+330612345678|
   ||+330712345678|
   ||06.12.34.56.78|
   ||06 12 34 56 78|
   ||06d12d34.h*56-78|
   ||+2258475|
   ||+65823|
   ```
3. Expected result:

   ```
   ||+33612345678|
   ||+33612345678|
   ||+33712345678|
   ||+33612345678|
   ||+33712345678|
   ||+33612345678|
   ||+33612345678|
   ||+33612345678|
   ||+2258475|
   ||+65823|
   ```
4. Current State

I tried to make this with sed. It's actually working with these expressions :

```
    sed -e "s/\b[^0-9]//g" sample > test
    sed -e "s/[a-z]//g" test > test2
    sed -e "s/\b[^0-9]//g" test2 > test3
    sed -e "s/^06/+336/g" test3 > test4
    sed -e "s/^07/+337/g" test4 > test5
    sed -e "s/^+3306/+336/g" test5 > test6
    sed -e "s/^+3307/+337/g" result
```

**BUT I don't know** how to make substitution in my CSV file, only on the third column.

Then, I tried with awk :

```
    awk '
    BEGIN {print substr($1,2); }
    {FS=OFS="|"} 
    {   
        gsub("\b[^0-9]","",$1);
        gsub("[a-z]","",$1);
        gsub("\b[^0-9]","",$1);
        gsub("^06","+336",$1);
        gsub("^07","+337",$1);
        gsub("^+3306","+336",$1);
        gsub("^+3307","+337",$1)
    } 1
    ' sample
```

but awk don't understand all the regex expressions.
The result when using awk :

```
    +33612345678|
    +33612345678|
    +33712345678|
    +33612345678|
    +33712345678|
    +336.12.34.56.78|
    +336 12 34 56 78|
    +3361234.*56-78|
    +2258475|
    +65823|
```

I would like use my regex expressions directly in my csv files, advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: only your third column will have data like this? or other columns can have similar data and data is separated by | pipes? in your sample input lines, I see two pipes in the beginning, is one pipe part of your data or both need to be considered as delimiters? just for the sample data, the following is working fine with me `cat sampledata.txt | sed 's/||0/||+33/; s/+330/+33/; s/[^0-9|+]*//g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is all you need:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
$3 != "" {
    gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",$3)
    sub(/^(33)?06/,"336",$3)
    sub(/^(33)?07/,"337",$3)
    $3 = "+" $3
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
||+33612345678|
||+33612345678|
||+33712345678|
||+33612345678|
||+33712345678|
||+33612345678|
||+33612345678|
||+33612345678|
||+2258475|
||+65823|
```

Comment: `sub(/^(33)?06/,"336",$3) ` in this substitution, if you just replace 330 with 33, it will cover both 3306 and 3307 cases,

Comment: @Ibraheem Right but then it'd also convert 3305, 3308, etc. which the OP didn't say she wanted changed and I assume she has good reason for being so specific in her text, code, and examples.

Comment: you are also right but as OP mentioned he is standardizing phone numbers, so I expect it won't have 0 after +33 in any case, but anyway, one extra line of code won't be bothersome to match the exact specification

Comment: Thank you ! however, the script will add "+" in empty rows. I will correct this with a simple sed.

Comment: No, don't add it with awk and then remove it with sed - just don't add it in the first place. You didn't show any empty lines in your input which is why it's not accounted for in the script but it's easily handled however you want it handled - I've updated it to one possibility (only modify $3 if it's non-null) and if that's not what you want then update your question to include how you want empty $3 and/or whole empty lines handled.

Answer (score 0):

I can get you a little closer.  I found a couple of mistakes with your awk script that should be corrected before making more progress.  First, the BEGIN statement looks to be in error.  Rather than print substr($1,2), it should just set the IFS and OFS.  As you probably already know, BEGIN only gets executed once.

Also, once the IFS is set to pipe '|', you'll need to modify the third field in each input line.  Thus, the target param for all your gsub calls should be $3, not $1.

Well, that's all I got for you.  I suspect the remainder of the issues I'm seeing with your output not matching the expected results is do to the reason you mention - different regexp handling.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} 
    {   
        gsub("\b[^0-9]","",$3);
        gsub("[a-z]","",$3);
        gsub("\b[^0-9]","",$3);
        gsub("^06","+336",$3);
        gsub("^07","+337",$3);
        gsub("^+3306","+336",$3);
        gsub("^+3307","+337",$3)
    } 
    1
' sample
```

Comment: YMMV with what any given awk thinks `\b` means.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !!